# sending udp broadcast from a docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot, networking, udp, docker-compose

I'm having a few docker containers (Using `docker-compose` and a single network - network-sol)

One of the containers is a `Spring Boot application` that sends UDP broadcast to the local network. 255.255.255.255 fails because It's the local broadcast address of **network-sol**

How can I broadcast UDP messages such as the "top local network" Will get those packets?  Do i have to use `directed broadcast address` for that?

P.S

broadcast works if the application is deployed outside of docker (part of the local network

Comment: I think this will only work when running on `network_mode: host`. But I am no networking expert to confirm that

Answer (score 7):

You should either run the service defined in your `docker-compose.yml` file with `network_mode: host`.

Alternatively you can publish the port of the container you intended to communicate with by publishing it using the following configuration. Note that the `/udp` is required for UDP communication to work.

```
service:
  ports:
    - "8080:8080/udp"
```

Comment: For some reason, It didn't work for me. Anyhow I'm upvoting because it seems like the logic answer

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten some luck out of [this](https://www.devwithimagination.com/2020/06/15/homebridge-docker-and-wake-on-lan/). The guide specifies sysctl parameters that are needed for broadcast forwarding from a docker network, you should then be able to either use his script or specify these parameters when running docker.

Answer (score 0):

- use docker compose file
- use bridge network

```
version: '3'
services:
  idhub-go:
    container_name: test
    image: 'nginx'
    ports:
      - "2641:2641/tcp"
      - "2641:2641/udp"
```